# WSO2IS access token refreshed for disabled user

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 Identity Server 5.9.0 I am using OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code. Access tokens are short-lived and are refreshed by refresh tokens. It implements current [recommendation for SPAs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-06#section-4) and it works fine.

I also configured [account disabling](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/account-disabling/) and I though that when I disable user which holds refresh token the user won't be able to get new access token. But `/oauth2/token` endpoint is issuing new tokens no matter if user is disabled or not. Is this expected? How can I deny given user to refresh access token?

Comment: Did you see any errors in the terminal?

Comment: @Janak I did not notice any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. If [locking](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/locking-a-specific-user-account/) is used instead of disabling then it works as expected. Submitted [issue](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/issues/1385) to WSO2.